# How to set title of Navigation Bar from a View Controller of a subview?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

I've a view controller having navigation bar in starting.
After some UIViewConrollers I have added a tabbar controller  where I've created four tab bars and four view controllers for each tab bar.
Now if I create tabbars with navigation bars related to each tab it shows two navigation bars at top, if create tabbars without navigation bar it will show only one tabbar but I am not able add title, corresponding to each tab view controller, to that navigation bar
 
Here is the code in which I created the tab bar

```
EventDetailViewController *firstViewController = [[EventDetailViewController alloc]init];
firstViewController.tabBarItem = [[[UITabBarItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Home" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Multimedia-Icon-Off.png"] tag:2]autorelease];                                 MoreInfo *secondViewController = [[MoreInfo alloc]init];
secondViewController.tabBarItem = [[[UITabBarItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Info" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Review-Icon-Off.png"] tag:0]autorelease];

PlaceInfoViewController *thirdViewController = [[PlaceInfoViewController alloc]init];
thirdViewController.tabBarItem = [[[UITabBarItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Lugar" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Place-icon-OFF.png"] tag:1]autorelease];

FavoritesViewController *forthViewController = [[FavoritesViewController alloc]init];
forthViewController.tabBarItem = [[[UITabBarItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Compartir" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Compartir-Icon-Off.png"] tag:3]autorelease];

UITabBarController *tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
tabBarController.viewControllers = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:firstViewController, secondViewController, thirdViewController, forthViewController, nil];
tabBarController.view.frame = self.view.frame;
[self.view addSubview:tabBarController.view];

[firstViewController release];
[secondViewController release];
[thirdViewController release];
[forthViewController release];
```

Comment: your question is not clear. you wants set title of navigation bar?

Comment: @stackBlue yeah..I want to the title of the navigation bar from a child view controller...

Comment: try it.. in viewDidLoad . self.title=@"my title";

Comment: @stackBlue it doesn't work..I already tried..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution myself by passing the reference of the navigation Item of the parent to the child view controller..thanx everyone for helping... :)

Answer (score 6):

You can obtain a reference to a view controller's `navigationItem` and set its `title`.

```
[[aViewController navigationItem] setTitle:@"My Title"];
```

Note that you'll want to embed all your view controllers in navigation controllers if you've not already done so. That way they'll actually get navigation bars with navigation items and you won't have to draw any of that yourself.

```
NSMutableArray *tabs = [NSMutableArray array];

UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:firstViewController];
[tabs addObject:nav];
nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:secondViewController];
[tabs addObject:nav];
...

[tabBarController setViewControllers:tabs];
```

---

**Edit:** Your tab bar controller is inside a navigation controller, so you need to get a reference to the tab bar controller first. Try `[[[self tabBarController] navigationItem] setTitle:...]` in the `viewDidLoad` method of your view controllers.

Comment: I already tried both methods...the first method doesn't work and in the second method I'll have 2 navigation bars and I want only the parent navigation bar that's why I didn't use the navigation controller instead of view controller...So suggest some other method to access the parent navigation bar in the child view controller...

Comment: @Shubham Is your tab bar controller already in a navigation controller?

Comment: Oh. In that case you probably have to go through the tab bar to get a reference to the navigation controller. I've edited my answer.

Comment: I tried this too but still it doesn't work :(...any other idea ?

Comment: Well, I guess I just can't understand how your view controllers are set up. If you `NSLog` `[[self tabBarController] navigationController]` in your view controller's `viewDidLoad`, is it set correctly?

Answer (score 2):

Please go to the EventDetailViewController.m and define the below method.

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
    self.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Catalogues", @"Catalogues");
    //self.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"book"];

}
return self;
}
```

Hope it will work then in each viewController.m define the above initializer.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set title for tabbar control.You have to use UINavigationBar on every viewcontrollers

For UINavigationBar:
 Drag Navigation bar to your xib/nib then add the title or do it programmatically

Answer (score 0):

you cannot set the title of navigation bar . set the title of view or sub views in navigation.
self.title=@"welcome";  simply set the title.